# Building small jars with kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

My jar files become huge, when I remove libraries from output the jar doesn't run.

These are my steps:

1. file -> project structure
2. add jar -> from modules with dependencies
3. select main class

Now, if I keep all extracted jars (libgdx, junit and kotlin) the jar file becomes too large. If I remove them all the jar won't run.

How do I know what to remove and what to keep?

Comment: You'll have to make a decision whether you want dependencies to be included in your JAR to make that self-contained, or whether you want to add dependencies to the CLASSPATH at runtime, keeping them in their own JARs. Pick one or the other... bundling some JARs within while expecting others on the CLASSPATH may get you into a real mess.

Comment: I would like for it to be self contained. I expected the jar file to be max 30mb, but it was 500-750mb.
Is this mostly Kotlins fault?

Comment: I have no practical experience with Kotlin, though the numbers seem high.  You'll have to check what went into the JAR. maybe there are some test-only classes not needed at runtime, or the standard Java classes got pulled in by mistake.